# Excel 365 Querytable unexpected behavior - Gets wrong cells format when gets empty

Tags: excel, excel-365

Since we have changed from Office 2010 to Office 365 we got an unexpected behavior with all our QueryTables.

We can refresh the QueryTables without problem while they are returning rows.
The problem appears the first time the QueryTable is refreshed and it returns 0 rows.

From that moment, if we refresh the QueryTable again, the new returned rows have lost the format. For example, columns with date format, are shown as numbers. Conditional formatting set on the header is applied to the rows... Basically it gets broken.

Using Excel 2010, this problem didn't exist.  We could get zero rows and then update the QueryTable again getting new rows, and they kept their format.

Have you experienced this problem in Excel 365? Is there any solution for this?

2022-04-04 17:00:00 EDIT:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the numeric format has been lost for column CreditLimit, and also the date format for column LastInvoiceDate.

Comment: Can you share the code that is being used to refresh the query tables?

Comment: No code is needed to reproduce the issue. Just right-click on the QueryTable and Refresh. The QueryTable gets the parameters from another cells, so no code is needed.

Comment: I believe @Sgdva is referring to the code you used to create the query and obtain the result that you are showing.  Without being able to reproduce your problem, the number of people who might be able to help you is considerably reduced.

Comment: I see you guys focused in the code, but i told that no code is involved here. You just can add a QueryTable by Excel menu > Data > Obtain Data > From other sources > From Microsoft Query. Then you set the data source, the query, and voilà, you have your Table. By these steps, in previous Excel versions, you got a QueryTable in your Excel. Using the same steps in new Excel versions you got a Table (this seems to be the new version of the QueryTables). What I would like is to solve the issue with the old QueryTables, without change them to Tables (ListObjects).